# How to globally replace pipe symbol "|" in string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I globally replace the `|` (pipe) symbol in a string? When I try to replace it with `"so|me|str|ing".replace(/|/g, '-')`, I get `"-s-o-|-m-e-|-s-t-r-|-i-n-g-"`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`|` has [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`A|B` means "match A or B"), so you need to escape it:

```
"so|me|str|ing".replace(/\|/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 8):

`|` means `OR`, so you have to escape it like this: `\|`

Answer (score 6):

Try using "so|me|str|ing".replace(/[|]/g, '-')

This is a great resource for working with RegEx: https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the pipe was coming as an variable, so I couldn't use any of these solutions. Instead, You can use:

```
let output_delimiter  ='|';
let str= 'Foo|bar| Test';

str.replace(new RegExp('[' + output_delimiter + ']', 'g'), '-')

//should be 'Foo-bar- Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, to do a substring replacement instead of a regex to replace the pipe character. However, the [String.prototype.**replace**()](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method will only replace **the first** substring instance, like here:

```
"so|me|str|ing".replace("|", "-"); // "so-me|str|ing" → WRONG
```

#### Possible workarounds:

1. Split the string into an array and join it with the new delimiter:

```
"so|me|str|ing".split("|").join("-"); // "so-me-str-ing" → RIGHT
```

2. Use a loop to replace one substring after the other.

```
var str = "so|me|str|ing"; 
while(str.indexOf("|") >= 0) {
  str = str.replace("|", "-"); // "so-me|str|ing" → RIGHT
}
```

#### Use `.replaceAll()`

Use the modern approach [String.prototype.**replaceAll**()](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) -- beware, that this method is only [supported by a few browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceAll) yet:

```
"so|me|str|ing".replaceAll("|", "-"); // "so-me-str-ing" → RIGHT
```